# Android: HTTP post Crash at DefaultHttpClient execute

Tags: android

I have the following code in Android, for posting request to a servlet. I am getting crash at `HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);` always , URL and everything is perfect, i don't know what is wrong here?

Could someone guide me please?

```
    Button loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Log.d("Cobrowse","Login Button Clicked");

                usrText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                pswdText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

                if ( usrText.length()>0 && pswdText.length()>0 ){
                    Log.d("Cobrowse: User name: ", usrText.getText().toString());
                    Log.d("Cobrowse: User name: ", pswdText.getText().toString());

                    System.out.println("Make Http Request");

                    // Creating HTTP client
                    // HttpClient                    
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();                     
                    // Creating HTTP Post
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.21:8080/CobrowingAuthSevlet/AuthenticationServlet?login=1234&password=1234");
                    // Making HTTP Request
                    try {
                         ****//IT IS CRASHING HERE****                      
                         HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                        // writing response to log
                        Log.d("Http Response: ", response.toString());
                        System.out.println("Http Response: " + response.toString());

                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        // writing exception to log
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // writing exception to log
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (Throwable t) { 
                        t.printStackTrace(); 
                    }

                }

        });
```

**UPDATED:**

I tried the AsyncTask, still facing the same issue: Nothing performs when reaches this line-> `TheTask().execute`

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Log.d("Cobrowse","Login Button Clicked");

                usrText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                pswdText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

                if ( usrText.length()>0 && pswdText.length()>0 ){
                    Log.d("Cobrowse: User name: ", usrText.getText().toString());
                    Log.d("Cobrowse: User name: ", pswdText.getText().toString());

                    System.out.println("Make Http Request");

                    new TheTask().execute("http://192.168.1.21:8080/CobrowingAuthSevlet/AuthenticationServlet?login=1234&password=1234");

                }
}
```

and,

```
class TheTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
{
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
        // update textview here
        System.out.println("onPostExecute");
        System.out.println("onPostExecute: result" + result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    System.out.println("doInBackground");

    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost method = new HttpPost(params[0]);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(method);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if(entity != null){
            return EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        }
        else{
            return "No string.";
        }
     }
     catch(Exception e){
         return "Network problem";
     }
}
}
```

Comment: you have to move the network call to AsyncTask...

Comment: NetworkOnMainThreadException : Use Async Task

Comment: Please check my updated code, I tried AsyncTask, but it is the same issue. It freezes when calling new TheTask().execute(url).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"This exception is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread". You should call asynctask. Look at this solution: [How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: Please check my updated code, I tried AsyncTask, but it is the same issue. It freezes when calling new TheTask().execute(url).

Comment: 03-20 05:55:19.173: D/dalvikvm(1976): threadid=11: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)